# Probability of a system to be in a state with energy $E$

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I found some questions that come close to this question but I couldn't find an exact duplicate of it, so, here goes: Suppose, we have a system whose state is determined by the generalized coordinates $p_1, ..., p_n$. Let the energy $E$ of this system be a function of these generalized coordinates; namely, $E = E(p_1, ..., p_n)$. The expression $Ce^{-\frac{E}{kT}}$, where $C$ is a normalization constant, $k$ is Boltzmann's constant and $T$ is the absolute temperature, is the probability density that the system is in a state with energy $E$. Then, what will be $Ce^{-\frac{E}{kT}} dp_1 ... dp_n$? It seems that the product in question will be the probability of the system to find itself in a state with energy $E$ and that probability should be 1, since, as said, $E$ is a function of all these $p_1, ..., p_n$ and whatever their change, the value of $E$ will be firmly established by their changed value. Is it true that $Ce^{-\frac{E}{kT}} dp_1 ... dp_n = 1$ or I'm missing something?

Comment: Hint: you are working in the canonical ensemble, where temperature, not energy, is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the fact that while $E$ is a variable, $dq_1 ... dq_n$ is a fixed infinitesimal canonical volume and anyone of the possible values of $E$ can correspond to that volume and not just one single $E$, as is presumed in the question. How was that expression arrived at?

It's probably easier to understand the problem if we observe a concrete example concerning a given number $N$ of particles, having various velocities, whereby we need to know what is the fraction $\frac{N_{\text{v}_x}}{N} = f_x(\text{v}_x)$ of particles having velocities between $\text{v}_x$ and $\text{v}_x + d\text{v}_x$ (for the sake of simplicity, we'll talk first about velocity component along $x$-axis). We should emphasize that, indeed, $f_x(\text{v}_x)$ is a function of $\text{v}_x$ because it will have different values for different $\text{v}_x$'s in the same interval $dx$. And, of course, $f_x(\text{v}_x)$ is such that $\int\limits_{\infty}^{\infty} f_x(\text{v}_x) dx = 1$. We may also call $f_x(\text{v}_x) dx$ the probability of particles to have velocity $\text{v}_x$ in the infinitesimal interval $d\text{v}_x$---multiplying $f_x(\text{v}_x) dx$ by the total number of particles $N$ gives the number of particles that have velocity $\text{v}_x$.

Now, how is energy coming into play in all this? Well, so far we talked about the component of velocity along the $x$-axis but that has no preference over the $y$ and $z$-axis velocity components. Therefore, we can generalize and, instead of talking about lengths along $x$, $y$ and $z$-axes separately, we can consider the entire length of the velocity vector; namely, $\text{v} = \left(\text{v}_x^2 + \text{v}_y^2 + \text{v}_z^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Likewise, probabilities along the different axes also have no preference and this symmetry allows us to write the compound probability (having in mind that common probability equals the product of the individual ones) as $f_x(\text{v}_x) dx.f_x(\text{v}_y) dy.f_z(\text{v}_z) dx = f_x(\text{v}_x)f_x(\text{v}_y)f_z(\text{v}_z) dxdydz$.

Here we will also utilize what we derived in the earlier paragraph, Thus, instead of the lengths comprising the velocity components, we will use the length of the velocity vector itself which is $\text{v} = \left(\text{v}_x^2 + \text{v}_y^2 + \text{v}_z^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and we will substitute  $f_x(\text{v}_x)f_x(\text{v}_y)f_z(\text{v}_z)$ by $F(\text{v}_x^2 + \text{v}_y^2 + \text{v}_z^2)$. We will make the observation that a function of that sum could be the product of individual exponential functions $Ae^{-B\text{v}_x^2} Ae^{-B\text{v}_y^2} Ae^{-B\text{v}_z^2} = A^3e^{-B \left( \text{v}_x^2 + \text{v}_y^2 + \text{v}_z^2 \right)} = A^3e^{-Bv^2}$. Now, this $A^3e^{-Bv^2}$ is indeed $F\left( \text{v}_x^2 + \text{v}_y^2 + \text{v}_z^2  \right)$ and we can plug it into the earlier expression $f_x(\text{v}_x)f_x(\text{v}_y)f_z(\text{v}_z) dxdydz$ to get $A^3e^{-Bv^2}dxdydz$.

Thus, it becomes clear why we get the quadratic expression in the exponent, which we can easily turn into $E$ by multiplying it by mass $m$ and dividing it by 2 to get $A^3e^{-B\frac{mv^2}{2}}dxdydz = A^3e^{-BE}dxdydz$. Now, I won't go further with this derivation, to determine what const $A$ and $B$ are because the point of the question was whether the product $A^3e^{-BE}dxdydz$ is unity. As seen, it is not, because $E$ may have different values for the same infinitesimal volume of the canonical variables, in this case $dxdydz$. It's another story that the expression at hand seems ripped off from the main idea Boltzmann had, using the whole this consideration as an element of the main question for the velocity distribution of particles. This expression $A^3e^{-BE}dxdydz$ itself has no particles explicitly in it and stands alone as just probability with no direct connection to anything. I suspect this was in the long run the stimulus for this question---the abstract nature of this probability, only indirectly connected to ponderable particles. Will be interesting to hear your thoughts on this.